# T-SQL in SQL Server 2008 - complex joining conditions or union of separate queries

Tags: sql-server, database, join

This is an execution speed issue.

There are two tables (example below). Main table and a detail table. The primary key of the main is referenced in the detail table on two distinct foreign key columns. The decision is based on a status column of main table.

There is about task table and taskdet table. Taskdet table has two references to Task table primary key. Task table primary key is referred in one of the taskdet table foreign key columns based on task type as follows:

```
iType=0 --> Original task with or without modifications 
            TaskDet.MainTskFk=Task.TaskID
iType=1 --> Task unchanged and assigned
            TaskDet.MainTskFk=Task.TaskID
iType=2 --> Change on original task
            TaskDet.ModiTskFk=Task.TaskID
Additionally detail table has a pointer to original task that gets modified
            TaskDet.MainTskFk=Task.TaskID of task table entry where its itype=0 
iType=3 --> Original Task completed
            TaskDet.ModiTskFk=Task.TaskID
```

The query to get the Original task compled and modifications on task for a person (PartnerFk Field) can be done in two ways.Using an Inner Join with complex criteria- SQL 1- or querying task and detail tables twines and union the results - SQL 2-.

Both of them work fine for small amount of data but when applied on a database that has 560k entries in task table and 250k entries in task detail table the SLQ 1 fails to run. I thought that querying the same table twice is slower then joining tables in a single query and using joining conditions like in SQL 1.

When is a performance improvement in querying the same table twice vs constructing complex joins?

SQL #1:

```
    SELECT 
        Task.TaskID
        ,Task.dtFrom
        ,Task.dtTo
        ,Case Task.itype When 2 Then TaskDet.MainTskFk When Else 0 END As ModfierOfTaskID
        ,TaskDet.ItemDesc
        ,TaskDet.EstimatedTime
    FROM 
        Task 
    INNER JOIN 
        TaskDet ON (Task.iType =3 and Task.TaskID = TaskDet.MainTskFK) 
                   OR (Task.iType =2 and Task.TaskID = TaskDet.ModiTskFK)
    WHERE
        Task.PartnerFK = 1
```

SQL #2:

```
SELECT 
    Task.TaskID
    ,Task.dtFrom
    ,Task.dtTo
    ,0 As ModfierOfTaskID
    ,TaskDet.ItemDesc
    ,TaskDet.EstimatedTime
FROM 
    Task 
INNER JOIN 
    TaskDet ON (Task.iType = 3 and Task.TaskID = TaskDet.MainTskFK)
WHERE  
    Task.PartnerFK = 1

UNION ALL

SELECT 
    Task.TaskID
    ,Task.dtFrom
    ,Task.dtTo
    ,TaskDet.MainTskFk As ModfierOfTaskID
    ,TaskDet.ItemDesc
    ,TaskDet.EstimatedTime
FROM 
    Task 
INNER JOIN 
    TaskDet ON (Task.iType =2 and Task.TaskID = TaskDet.ModiTskFK)
WHERE
    Task.PartnerFK = 1
```

Tables structures and data:

`Task` Table has `TaskID` as its primary key

`Task` table:

```
    TaskID  dtFrom             dtTo             Notes                    PartnerFK  iType
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      1 01-01-2014  20-03-2014  Original Task Requires modification         1       0
      2 18-02-2014  20-04-2014  Assigned task and unchanged                 4       1
      3 28-01-2014  18-02-2014  Original Task assiged not started unchanged 4       0
      4 02-04-2014  05-05-2014  Changes required on assigned task           1       2
      5 31-12-2013  01-04-2014  Assigned task and unchanged                 2       1
      6 12-03-2014  24-03-2014  Original task completed                     1       3
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

`TaskDet` table:

```
DetID   MainTskFK ModiTskFK         Itemdesc    EstimatedTime
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1    1          Prepare end of month letter            200
2    1          Reconcile bank statements              150
3    2          tsk1                                   200
4    2          tsk2                                   150
5    5          Conclude lease agreement                25
6    5          Get sales figures as EOM               100
7    5          Glass cleaning                          35
8    6          Prepare car exhibition                 500
9    6          Conclude exhibition lease agreements    85
10   1      4   Requires additional Time                50
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with complex join criteria is that it can make it impossible for SQL Server to use indexes for the joins, it can cause spills to tempdb because the data doesn't fit in the memory or additional sorts are needed because the data isn't any more joined on clustered indexes (or some other expensive operation happens).

For this particular case you'll probably figure it out quite easily by comparing the actual execution plan and the i/o amounts shown when you turn "statistics io" on for the both cases.